# How to plot different columns with different kind of plot (bar & line) without using matplotlib (only using pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe like below:

```
   month start end
0 2018-1  1000   0
1 2018-2  1100 0.1
2 2018-3  1400 0.3
3 2018-4  700 -0.5
```

If I would like to plot 'start' column with line, and 'end' column with bar (x axis should be month) with only using pandas plot function in same graph, how should I do that?
+
for bar chart, it would be preferred to have the chart with a black horizontal line at end=0, and bars color-coded such that positive returns are green and negative returns are red.

I started to try

```
ax = df.plot(figsize=(10,5), x='month', y='start')
df.plot(figsize=(10,5), x='month', y='end', kind='bar', ax=ax)
ax
pass
```

But it looked not what I wanted.
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with the current chart? Could you be more specific?

Comment: I added the figure. The line was gone, and x values were overlapped, and I haven't tried end=0 dotted line and color coding for bar chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you need something like this. How to color the bars conditionally has been taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22311139/matplotlib-bar-chart-choose-color-if-value-is-positive-vs-value-is-negative). I took the data you provided in the question from clipboard

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df['positive'] = df['end'] > 0
ax = df.plot(figsize=(10,5), x='month', y='start')
ax1 = df.plot(figsize=(10,5), x='month', y='end', kind='bar', color=df.positive.map({True: 'g', False: 'r'}), 
         ax=ax,  secondary_y=True)
ax1.plot([0, len(df['end'])], [0, 0], color='black')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Sheldore  If I would like to make it two separate y axis, how should I edit this code?

Comment: I mean one y axis for line plot (left side) and another y axis for bar plot (right side). During calculation, I found the bar plot values are between 0.1-0.4 so if I plot them together bar plot was too small to recognize. So I edit the 'end' column value accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
ax=df.plot(figsize=(10,5),x="month",y="End",kind="bar")
df.plot(x='month', y='Start',kind="line",ax=ax)
```

Works fine for me.