# Issues in displaying negative values on bar chart in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a bar chart with both positive and negative values using Matplotlib and experiencing difficulty in getting the negative values to show on Y axis. When the code is run, it'll correctly display all positive values (marked in red color) but the negative ones are not showing at all.
Instead I'm getting a duplication of the positive values for the string marked "y1". Please see Image 1 attached and my code below.

[image: Image 1]

The code I've used is:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

data = pd.read_csv("C:\samplefile.csv")
fig = plt.figure()
figure(figsize = (22,3))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
x = data['Timing Event']
y = data['Diff Latency'].diff(periods = 1) > 0
y1 = data['Diff Latency'].diff(periods = 1) < 0
y_pos = np.arange(len(x))
plt.bar(y_pos, y, color=(1.0, 0, 0, 0.7))
plt.bar(y_pos, y1, color=(0, 0.6, 0, 0.7))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The dataset has 2 columns Timing Event in numbers eg.(0,1,2,3....) and used as index and "Diff Latency" which has both negative and positive values. Sample dataset is attached below:

```
Timing Event    Diff Latency
     0               -4
     1                3
     2                1
     3               -1
     4                2
```

Comment: What is your expected result like?

Comment: Hello gmds, the expected result looks like the attached image (Image 1 link above), however the green columns should be displayed on the negative side of the axis. I can generate the negative values on string y but the colour will be red and the end user is not able to tell the difference visually.

Comment: You are not plotting negative values but boolean values. Is `plt.bar(y_pos, -1 * y1, color=(0, 0.6, 0, 0.7))` what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to plot the positive and negative values in different colored bars, you can directly use pandas plotting based on the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22311139/matplotlib-bar-chart-choose-color-if-value-is-positive-vs-value-is-negative)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = pd.DataFrame({'Timing_Event':[0,1,2,3,4], 'Diff_Latency':[-4, 3, 1, -1, 2]})
data['sign'] = data['Diff_Latency'] > 0

data['Diff_Latency'].plot(kind='bar', color=data.sign.map({True: (1.0, 0, 0, 0.7), False: (0, 0.6, 0, 0.7)}), 
                      ax=ax)
ax.axhline(0, color='k')
```

[image]

Comment: How do you do this? To force the 0 point of the Y-Axis to be at the center?